# Using data passed from parent to child classes for adding points on globe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, parameter-passing, react-class-based-component

I am working on a fun project, to help boost my knowledge and understanding of ReactJS coupled with ThreeJS, but have run into an issue for passing in data from the parent class to the functions in the child class. Right now my project looks as follows:
**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Globe, Building, BuildingBody} from './components';
import styles from './App.module.css';
import { fetchData } from './assets/api';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
      data: {},
      state: '',
      isMounted: true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const fetchedData = fetchData();
      this.setState({ data: fetchedData});
      
  }

  handleStateChange = (state) => {
      const fetchedData = fetchData(state);
      this.setState({data: fetchedData, state: state})
  }
  render() {
    const { data, state, isMounted=true } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.dataContainer}>
          <Building handleStateChange={this.handleStateChange.bind(this)}/>
          <BuildingBody data = {data} state={state} />
        </div>
        <Globe data = {data} state={state}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My ThreeJS portion looks like this:
**Globe.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

import earthmap from '../../assets/images/earthmap4k.jpg';
import earthbump from '../../assets/images/earthbump4k.jpg';
import earthspec from '../../assets/images/earthspec4k.jpg';
import particle from '../../assets/images/particle.jpg';
import clouds from '../../assets/images/earthhiresclouds4K.jpg';

class Globe extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            state: props.state,
            data: props.data
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state.data)
        console.log(this.state.state)
        this.createScene();
        this.addSceneObjects();
        this.startAnimation();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize);
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestID);
        this.controls.dispose();
    }

    createScene = () => {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 720 / 480, 0.1, 1000 );
        this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.mount);
        this.controls.enableZoom = false
        
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialiasing: true });
        this.renderer.setSize( 720, 480 );

        this.mount.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
        this.camera.position.z = 20;
    };

    addSceneObjects = () => {
        this.addLight();
        this.addEarth();
        this.addCoord();
    };

    addLight = () => {
        const lights = [];
        lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, .3, 0);
        lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, .4, 0);
        lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, .7, 0);
        lights[3] = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x706570 );

        lights[0].position.set(0, 200, 0);
        lights[1].position.set(200, 100, 400);
        lights[2].position.set(-200, -200, -50);

        this.scene.add(lights[0]);
        this.scene.add(lights[1]);
        this.scene.add(lights[2]);
        this.scene.add(lights[3]);
    };

    addEarth = () => {
        const earthMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( earthmap );
        const earthBumpMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( earthbump);
        const earthSpecMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( earthspec);

        const earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10, 32, 32 );
        const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: earthMap,
            bumpMap: earthBumpMap,
            bumpScale: 0.10,
            specularMap: earthSpecMap,
            specular: new THREE.Color('grey')
        });

        this.earthSphere = new THREE.Mesh( earthGeometry, earthMaterial );
        this.scene.add( this.earthSphere );

        const earthGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 36, 36 );
        const cloudsTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( clouds );
        const materialClouds = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff, 
            map: cloudsTexture, 
            transparent:true, 
            opacity:0.4
        });

        this.earthClouds = new THREE.Mesh( earthGeo, materialClouds );
        this.earthClouds.scale.set( 1.015, 1.015, 1.015 );
        this.earthSphere.add( this.earthClouds );
    };

    addCoord = () => {
        this.particleMat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            size: 0.25,
            //map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(particle),
            //transparent: true,
            //blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            //depthWrite: false
        });

        this.particleGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 64, 64);

        this.particleGeo.vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
            const lat = 31.688372;
            const lon = -106.405023;
            const radius = 10;
            const phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180);
            const theta = (lon+180)*(Math.PI/180);
            vertex.x = -((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
            vertex.z = ((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta));
            vertex.y = ((radius) * Math.cos(phi));
        });

        this.particleSystem = new THREE.Points(
            this.particleGeo,
            this.particleMat
        );

        this.particleSystem.name = 'particleSystem';

        this.earthClouds.add(this.particleSystem);
    };

    startAnimation = () => {
        this.earthSphere.rotation.y += 0.0009;
        //this.earthClouds.rotation.y += 0.001;
        this.requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimation);
        //requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimation);
    
        this.controls.update();

        this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    };

    handleWindowResize = () => {
        const width = this.mount.innerWidth;
        const height = this.mount.innerHeight;

        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        this.camera.aspect = width / height;

        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data)
        console.log(this.props.state)
        return (
        <>
            <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} data = {this.props.data} state = {this.props.state}>
                
            </div>
        </>
        )
    }
}

export default Globe;
```

The data from the **App.js** does get passed into the `render()` function of my **Globe.jsx**. However, I am wanting to take that data and pass it into the **Globe.jsx** body for populating the points using

```
this.particleGeo.vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
            const lat = **INSERT DATA.latitude**;
            const lon = **INSERT DATA.longitude**;
            const radius = 10;
            const phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180);
            const theta = (lon+180)*(Math.PI/180);
            vertex.x = -((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
            vertex.z = ((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta));
            vertex.y = ((radius) * Math.cos(phi));
        });
```

but I am currently lost in accomplishing this task. I know it is possible to access the data in a component which is a function, but when attempting to convert my **Globe.jsx** to a function instead of a class, my code breaks (after changing `this.state` to variables/lets/etc.). If you all could please help me out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly the problem here, what error are you getting? You mention you convert your class to functional component, are you asking for how to access props in functional components?

Comment: I am trying to access the data passed from props into the function ```addCoord``` so I can populate latitude and longitude on the globe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access props with this.props inside functions:

```
addCoord = () => {
    const data = this.props.data;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, and for populating longitude and latitude, would that be in a for loop such as ```for(let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const lat = data[i].latitude;
            const lon = data[i].longitude;
             ...
}
```
?

Comment: Yes you can iterate over your data and call your function  with each individiual point. Change your addCoord function to accept point, and call it for each point.

Comment: it turns out my original code was working as intended. But due to my using a local-JSON file, versus an actual url, the data is not loading onto the globe because it is initially set to empty. I have to figure out why that is and improve it. But thank you for the help regardless!